# What microphone is used by sound engineers in foley?

Tags: audio-recording

I'm looking to record some sound in a "closed" setting similar to sound engineers when I toured the foley section of a movie production. Unfortunately, there wasn't a Q & A opportunity.

I'm looking for make and model, and any advice on differences (if any) between different use (for example for recording different frequencies).

I intend to process the recording on a Mac (not sure if this matters, but just in case it does).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an indie filmmaker.  I've done sound for my friends sometimes. 
The sound guy I know (and we're super low budget indie)  uses the same mic he booms with on set.

He tried using a better one that was usb based but the sound was much different in quality then the sound recorded on the day.

For reference he's using the 
Rhode NTG 2 http://www.rodemic.com/mics/ntg-2 (about $300)
It uses XLR cables which can be a pain in the but for getting it in to your comp.
I also have an NTG 2 and I still prefer my 
Rhode Video mic http://www.rodemic.com/mics/videomic 
(it's cheaper and doesn't use XLR cables) ($150ish)

You could also try something like a Blue Yeti http://www.bluemic.com/yeti/ (about $150 but it was on sale for $75 at staples the other week) I have 1 of those and it has multiple settings so you might be able to find one that works.  The blue yeti is good because you can use it for a lot of other stuff like podcast recording or music.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Have you encountered any limitation in terms of sound quality with your setup with the Rhode Video mic versus the NTG 2?

Comment: No I have never had issues with the video mic.  We shot several episodes of our webseries with both running and I ended up using the Video Mic mainly.  It seemed to capture the scene more evenly. I'm not pro at sound though I just know my way around a Zoom H4N , boom pole and mic

Comment: Will look up the website. It's a start. Again, thanks for sharing. Very much appreciated.

Comment: It's worth noting that mics that use XLR connectors will almost certainly give you better sound.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm also an independent filmmaker ultra zero budget indie sorta guy and i just started a foley web-series and we are using the Yeti Pro by blue, a bit more professional but same idea.

Comment: Welcome to AVP!  Thanks for the answer.  It is customary to disclose your affiliation with any linked content.  Also, It would be better for posterity if you included the relevant information from the link in your answer itself.  Links have a tendency to die :)

Comment: Deleted signature type link from answer.